# Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему когда мы добавляем числовой тип и строчный тип, то

Tags: javascript

выводится строчный, а когда от числового вычитаем строчный, то получается числовой?

Comment: так решил сделать Брендан Эйх

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, странно

Comment: В этой статейке всё более чем доступно расписано : [click](https://learn.javascript.ru/operators)

Comment: что Вам кажется странным?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, странно то, что он решил так сделать

Comment: В статье не указано почему именно так.

Comment: Чтобы превратить строчку в число, достаточно перед строкой добавить дополнительный символ '+'. Например если `4 + '5' = 45`, то `4 + +'5' = 9`. Видимо решили, что так будет легче, чем везде в коде лишний раз проверять все куски строк на наличие чисел...

Comment: Выскажу предположение. Js как и PHP являются языками с неявной типизацией данных. И чтобы JS как-то определить число ли это он пробует строку преобразовать в число и если у него это получилось, то это будет числом.  Думаю так оно и есть. Если что специалисты по js поправят.

Answer (score 1):

На этот вопрос нельзя однозначно ответить.

ИМХО - для потенциальной возможности писать лаконичные конструкции.

Операция вычитания определена только для числовых примитивов, по этому получается логично что результат вычитания это число и оба аргумента операции вычитания приводятся к числу, затем происходит вычитание.

С другой стороны - сложение определено как для строк (конкатенация) так и для чисел, нужно было как-то действовать в ситуации неопределенности, когда один аргумент сложения число а второй строка и вот тут создатель javascript Брендан Эйх решил что если хоть один из аргументов сложения это строка - то это конкатенация.

В противном случае не возможно было бы инлайн из числа получить строку, без явного приведения типов и была бы невозможна конструкция:

```
var left = 20 + 'px';
```